Trace the ip_recv() function using BPF, but only packets from the lo interface can be captured
I wrote a BPF program to trace the ip_rcv function, but it only captures packets from the lo interface.
#include "vmlinux.h"
#include <bpf/bpf_core_read.h>
#include <bpf/bpf_helpers.h>
#include <bpf/bpf_tracing.h>

char LICENSE[] SEC("license") = "Dual BSD/GPL";

SEC("kprobe/ip_rcv")
int BPF_KPROBE(ip_rcv,
struct sk_buff* skb,
struct net_device* dev,
struct packet_type* pt,
struct net_device* orig_dev) {
    const char* devname;

    devname = BPF_CORE_READ(dev, name);

    if(devname[0] == 'l' && devname[1] == 'o') {
        // bpf_printk("recv packet from lo device");
    } else {
        bpf_printk("recv packet from %s device", devname);
    }

    return 0;
}

I identify which network card it comes from by the name of the printing device.

Can you describe how you attached the program and how you generated non-loopback traffic?
